# MonoDevelop: Reformatting Code - Tune Down

Tags: mono, xamarin.ios, monodevelop, xamarin.android

MonoDevelop 3.0 is great, but it's a little too over zealous on reformatting.

When I enter the code:

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer (typeof(TDestination),extraTypes);
```

Then press CTRL+SHIFT+F to format the code, it change these lines to put one parameter on each line making it hard to read when the function calls or lambda expressions are long.

```
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer (
                    typeof(TDestination),
                    extraTypes
        );
```

How do I get MonoDevelop to leave the line breaks as they are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Preferences >> Source Code >> Code Formatting >> C# Source Code. Select a custom policy, press the "C# Format" tab, and press the "Edit" button. I hope that helps!

Comment: When I set the option to not put a new line, when I place the ); at the end, ti still wraps the entire code.

Comment: I talked to one of the Xamarin guys on their IRC channel, and he says "that's a known bug in MD 3.0, it'll be fixed in 3.0.3"